# How to style Angular material-tab-panel (and its tabs) on Dart?

Tags: sass, dart, angular-dart

I would like to know how to style an Angular material-tab-panel (and its tabs) on Dart.

I'm having trouble working with SASS, which I think is the way of doing it.

Currently I have something like:

```
<material-tab-panel id="my_material_tab_panel">

    <material-tab label="First Tab" class="my-material-tabs"></material-tab>

    <material-tab label="Second Tab" class="my-material-tabs"></material-tab>

</material-tab-panel>
```

EDIT: I'm importing Angular Components and registering Material Tab (component and panel) as a directive:

```
import "dart:async";
import "dart:html";

import "package:angular/angular.dart";
import "package:angular_components/angular_components.dart";

@Component(
    selector: "view-test",
    styleUrls: const ["test.css"],
    templateUrl: "test.html",
    directives: const [
        CORE_DIRECTIVES,
        materialDirectives,
        MaterialTabPanelComponent,
        MaterialTabComponent
    ]
)
// (...)
```

**What I would like to do is to:**

1. change tab text color;
2. change tab background color;
3. change selected tab background color;
4. change bottom border color on selected tab.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I recently updated the example page to show using one of the material tab scss mixins to customize the color. https://github.com/dart-lang/angular_components_example/blob/master/lib/src/material_tab_demo/material_tab_demo.scss. Have you had a chance to look at that yet?

Answer (score 0):

You should use provided mixins:
https://github.com/dart-lang/angular_components/blob/master/angular_components/lib/material_tab/_mixins.scss

Inside your component's scss file you can do:

```
@import path/material_tab/mixins;

material-tab {
  @include tab-panel-tab-strip-width('', 200px);
}
```

There are mixins for most of your need, if something is missing please send a PR on github.

Comment: 404 not found on the link